# Monkey Runner import giving error

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i created an empty file an named it something.py, and then i just copied the lines of code from the android developer website. However, if i try to run it, i get an

ImportError: No module named com.android.monkeyrunner

Is there something i am missing? There doesn't seem to be anything at the android developer website that addresses this issue. Here are the lines of code

```
       from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
       device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
       device.installPackage('myproject/bin/Stamp_Client.apk')
       package = 'com.example.main'
       activity = 'com.example.Stamp_Client'
       runComponent = package + '/' + activity
       device.startActivity(component=runComponent)
       device.press('KEYCODE_BUTTON_SELECT','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_U','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_S','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_E','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_R','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_P','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_A','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_S','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_S','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER','DOWN_AND_UP')
       device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER','DOWN_AND_UP')
```

Comment: I've got the same issue in Windows...

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you run:

```
$ monkeyrunner yourfile.py
```

instead of:

```
$ python yourfile.py
```

Comment: If `yourfile.py` is not in the `monkeyrunner` directory, you will need give a full path to `yourfile.py`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are missing the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
```

that is if you are using Linux or OSX, for Windows you probably have to create a batch file.